# QtWebKit/QWebView: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, qt, webkit, qtwebkit

I am trying to build a an example that I found at https://github.com/tranter/qt-google-calendar/. When I go to build I get an error stating that there is no such directory for QtWebKit/QWebView. I am on Qt 4.8.6 and have confirmed that `QT += webkit` is in the *.pro file. I can confirm that my version of Qt was compiled with the `-webkit` option configured. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and `libqtwebkit-dev` is installed. Any ideas what else could be causing this?

To clarify, the exact error is `QtWebKit/QWebView: No such file or directory` it points to the instance of `include <QtWebKit/QWebView>` in `ui_logindialog.h`

Comment: Please include the exact error message in your question

Comment: "... my version of Qt ..." -- are you mixing Qt versions maybe? `libqtwebkit-dev` contains the webkit headers, so if you use the *distro-provided* qmake, you should not be getting these errors.